# Integer Shared preference allways returns 0

Tags: android, passwords, sharedpreferences

I am trying to code a simple password check for protecting the settings of my app. The password should be saved in a shared preference. The main calls the setPassword when the sharedPreference returns zero. This is to make sure that there will be a password set, when somebody tries to enter the settings the first time. The setPassword should then set a password and safe it in the sharedPreference. But when checking if there was a password set, the sharedPreference allways returnes 0.

this is my main:

```
final Intent intentSetPasswords = new Intent(this, SetPasswordActivity.class);
    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    passwordToCheck = sharedPreferences.getInt("PASSWORDSETTINGS", 0);

    //setting button on click listener
    buttonSetings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //check if a password was set muss Überarbeitet werden
            passwordToCheck = sharedPreferences.getInt("PASSWORDSETTINGS", 0);
            Log.e("password", ""+ passwordToCheck);
            if(passwordToCheck==0){
                startActivity(intentSetPasswords);
            }else{
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PasswordCheckActivity.class));
            }
        }
    });
```

and tis is my setPassword:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_password);

    final Intent intentSettings = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);


    buttonSetPassword = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSetPassword);
    textViewSetPassword = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewSetPasswordText);
    editTextPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordNumericSettingsSetPassword);
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    buttonSetPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            counterButton++;
            switch (counterButton){
                case 1:
                    password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                    if (password.length() == 4){
                        Log.d("First Password", "taken");
                        buttonSetPassword.setText("Confirm Password!");
                        editTextPassword.setText("");
                    }else{
                        Log.d("First Password", "not taken");
                        textViewSetPassword.setText("The Password must be\nfour numbers long!");
                        password = "";
                        editTextPassword.setText("");
                        counterButton=0;
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    passwordToConfirm = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                    if (Integer.parseInt(passwordToConfirm)  == Integer.parseInt(password)){

                        Log.e("password", password);
                        Log.e("passwordToConfirm", passwordToConfirm);
                        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("PASSWORDS", 0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        editor.putInt("PASSWORDSETTINGS", Integer.parseInt(password));
                        editor.commit();
                        startActivity(intentSettings);
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        textViewSetPassword.setText("The passwords aren't the same!\nTry again!");
                        buttonSetPassword.setText("Set Password");
                        editTextPassword.setText("");
                        passwordToConfirm = "";
                        password = "";
                        counterButton = 0;
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I guess there is a problem with the sharedPreference, but I don't get what.

Comment: What do you want isn't clear. If shared preferences value wasn't set before it would return default value. In your case default value is zero. `sharedPreferences.getInt("PASSWORDSETTINGS", 0)` second parameter of `getInt()` is default value.

Comment: ok, so why does it still return 0, even if a password was set? In the setPassword is a value written in the shared preference. But after setting the password the sharedPreference still returns zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, check `counterButton` value and ensure **case 2 branch** is executed.
Secondly the `sharedPreferences` for setting and the `sharedPreferences` for getting  should be same. you could do like this:

```
private final static String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs"; //define two class fields
private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);//in activity Oncreate() methods. 


//and set or get in other place as you want.
```

Answer (score 1):

Easily use the library below to manage data

https://github.com/orhanobut/hawk

Answer (score 0):

First you get sharedpreferences like this

```
final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Later when setting the password you get it as below

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("PASSWORDS", 0);
```

They're two different sharedpreferences. Use the first sharedpreferences.
For more info refer to this page https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences